# reference a $scope by using a string variable as the scope name e.g. $scope.[stringVar]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change the value of a scope in the controller, but the name of the specific scope isn't explicitly know, and will be sent to the controller function as a variable.

Example function with explicit scope name is:

```
$scope.resetIsCustomer = function () {
    $scope.cust = null;
};
```

Example of what I need would be:

```
$scope.resetQuestionScope = function (scopeName) {
    $scope.scopeName = null;
};
```

I'm unsure of what to search or of a possible way to do this, similar things are when referencing elements by ID/Name in Jquery they can be constructed  such as `$('[name="' + this.id + 'pie"]')` or checked to exist with `typeof window[this.id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.resetQuestionScope = function (scopeName) {
    $scope[scopeName] = null;
};
```

Same as in plain js, well angular is plain js :)

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 2;
obj['a'] = 2;
var p = 'a';
obj[p] = 2;
```